# Tomcat can't find Log4j library

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I'm trying to deploy a `.war` using Tomcat 8.5.56 (I have to use this version for company policy), it logs with Log4j and it is all setted at `WEB-INF/web.xml` as you can see here:

```
...
    <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>LogClassName</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-value>com.lutris.logging.Log4jLogger</env-entry-value>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
    <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>Log4j</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-value>../conf/log4j.xml</env-entry-value>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
...
```

When I search the application url, I got a 500 Server error with the next message:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Initialization of logger failed
caused by class com.lutris.util.ConfigException: Key "LogFile" not found in configuration.
    com.lutris.appserver.server.httpPresentation.servlet.HttpPresentationServlet.throwServletException(Unknown Source)
    com.lutris.appserver.server.httpPresentation.servlet.HttpPresentationServlet.init(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After a long search I found that this problem comes up because it cant't find the LogClassName class and try to use the default logger, but all the `.jar`s files are at the lib path in `tomcat_folder/lib`. At first I thought it would be solved if I put that `.jar`s at the app lib folder (`tomcat_folder/webapps/application/WEB-INF/lib`) but the problem is still there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.